# Perpetual Inventory Valuation- odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I created 3 chart of accounts as follow with type current asset:

1. 23600 Stock Interim Account (Received)
2. 14600 Stock Interim Account (Delivered)
3. 14000 Stock Valuation Account

And assigned  to product category.

1. Set costing method as Average and inventory valuation as Perpetual.
2. Created a purchase order and received products
   Then system created journal entries as follow.
   [image]

   4. When i create an vendor invoice from same purchase order, in product lines it automatically choose  `501100 Cost of Goods Sold in Trading` instead of `23600 Stock Interim Account (Received)`. 
      [image]

Did i configure anything wrong?

How can i resolve this?

Comment: You should aks this kind of question in odoo forum.

Comment: I already asked

Comment: Have you check res.partner's accouts. This might be coming from that.

Comment: @Keval, you mean Payable/receivable account ?

Comment: @KbiR Yes. Configuration from this field may affect you.